# Difficulty to understand a notion of optimality involving random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, logic

I consider a subset $\mathcal{W}$ of $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$.

In a paper I am reading it is said that a random variable $X\in\mathcal{W}$ is optimal if it is of the form

$$
X = \mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid \sigma(Z)\right]
$$

where $Y$ is **an arbitrary element** of $\mathcal{W}$.

My question is the following : is this mean that $X$ should verify that

$$
X= \mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid \sigma(Z)\right]
$$

For all $Y\in\mathcal{W}$ or only that there exists (possibly more than one) $Y\in\mathcal{W}$ such that

$$
X= \mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid \sigma(Z)\right]
$$

?

I think that the statement as presented  and the order of the sentences confused me.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: It means there exists $Y$.